# Transfer an object from one page to another in asp.net without use of Session

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, object

I have a web application with 10 pages. Page1.aspx, page2.aspx......page10.aspx.
I have a button on Page2.aspx page. When I will click that button, an object will transfer from Page2.aspx to page4.aspx, page7.aspx and Page10.aspx. I cannot use session state. How do I pass an object from page2 to page4 and so on?

Comment: "I can not use session," - please put a little effort into explaining why? Maybe other solutions are also ruled out? Or maybe, you can't use session, per *your* understanding of it, but it is in fact a feasible approach.

Comment: Hi, Yes, I know but i faced this question in a client interview phase. I told them we will go for Session, but they ask me there is another way that we can pass object from one page to another what is that???

Answer (score 0):

If your site must be stateless you can pass data from page to page through form elements.

There are various choices within this - you could serialize the object and pass it as a single form variable, or you could pass each of the object's properties as a form variable, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use context object. Before you use this you need to check the lifecycle of context object.

[Context.Items clears during page refresh/transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093431/context-items-clears-during-page-refresh-transfer)